# foreach continue is not working when inside RunWithElevatedPrivileges

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Below code keep executing when error arises,

```
    foreach($url in Get-Content $urlsDir) 
    {
        try
        {
            // do something
            // declare X
        }
        catch
        {
            // write host or soemthing with exception
            continue
        }
        finally
        {
            // dispose X
        }
    }
```

but when I put this code in RunWithElevatedPrivileges, it completely stops on first error and won't continue execution,

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges({ 
        # Iterate through all webs in a text file
        foreach($url in Get-Content $urlsDir) 
        {
            try
            {
                // do something
                // declare X
            }
            catch
            {
                // write host or soemthing with exception
                continue
            }
            finally
            {
                // dispose X
            }
        }
  });
```

Comment: `continue` does not skip the `finally` - it is 'guaranteed' to run, even when an exception occurs.  Get more information here: [about_Try_Catch_Finally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-6).  Not sure if this is causing your issue, but maybe something you think you are skipping is actually executing and causing a problem.

Comment: @boxdog it's not about skipping finally... it's about not continuing with the foreach loop on exception

Comment: The point I was making is that when you catch your exception, the `continue` does not cause it to simply go to the next item in the loop, but runs whatever is in the `finally`, which itself could cause a catastrophic error (though I'm not sure what that might be).  Does it fail on any exception (e.g. divide by zero), and if `finally` is empty?

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to whether or not you've specified an ErrorAction, I'm not sure how this relates to try catch though. I have done something similar where my foreach would not stop unless explicitly stated.

Basically you need to specify what should happen if an error occurs on each call, as so

```
Call-Something $SomeParam -ErrorAction Stop
```

and unless you specify it as above for each call or in the start of your script as below errors can be silently ignored.

```
// at the start of your script
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
```

For more information you can read about ErrorAction in powershell here for instance
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2013/06/09/an-introduction-to-error-handling-in-powershell/

And according to [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-6&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-Microsoft.PowerShell.Core) these are the valid values:

> Stop: Displays the debug message and stops executing. Writes an error to the console.
>
> Inquire: Displays the debug message and asks you whether you want to continue. Note that adding the Debug common parameter to a command--when the command is configured to generate a debugging message--changes the value of the $DebugPreference variable to Inquire.
>
> Continue: Displays the debug message and continues with execution.
>
> SilentlyContinue: No effect. The debug message is not (Default) displayed and execution continues without interruption.